# Find number of zeros at the end of $2007!$ using greatest integer function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, permutations

How to solve this question using greatest integer function? 
I used logical thinking to get answer but I want to solve this question using greatest integer function.

Answer:  $500$

Please explain in detail

Please don't close my question. Since I am just a high school student seeking help from teachers.

Comment: Umm what is the $\LaTeX$ for floor bounds?

Comment: I don't need just steps, I need it's explanation. Please Help

Comment: Okay consider that $10=2 \cdot 5$. So how many times can you divide $2007!$ by $5$ without getting a remainder

Comment: $25=5 \cdot 5$, $125= 25 \cdot 5$, $625= 125 \cdot 5$ so you have to consider each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily justify that there are more factors of $2$ in $2007!$ than there are factors of $5$. So you get a $0$ for every number divisible by $5$, like $5,10,15,20,...$. It is easy to see that there are $401$ such numbers ($5\cdot1,5\cdot2,...,5\cdot401$). But all multiples of $25$ are counted only once, when they contain at least an extra factor of $5$. There are $80$ such multiples, so we add $80$ extra zeros. Then one notice that $125$ and multiples contribute an extra zero each. And then you need to repeat the procedure for $625=5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot5$. You will end up with $401+80+16+3=500$. Note that $625\cdot5=3125$ is greater than $2007$, so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: I don't understand that if we take divisibility of a number by 5 is proportional to number of zeros.... Then why we need to divide it again by 25 , 125 s

Comment: If I have $2\cdot5$ I get one zero. If I have $16\cdot15$ I still get one zero. But if I have $24\cdot25$ I get two zeros. I accounted for one of them when I say that $25$ is a multiple of $5$

Comment: Since there are more factors of $2$ than there are factors of $5$ in $2007!$ Then $2007!$ is going to equal "stuff"$\cdot 2\cdot 2 \cdots 2 \cdot (2\cdot 5)\cdot(2 \cdot 5) \cdots (2\cdot 5)$